# Powershell quick toggle available commands

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line

I see in the following image from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs) that they are switching quickly between available commands and parameters. I know this is a noob question but can someone please tell me how they do it? Also does this functionality have an actual name, common in other shells?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I'm aware of auto-completion in shells. However in this scenario this is not what's happening. The user initially types "**-?**" and then quickly navigates between "search", "list", "install", "upgrade" etc. Then they type "no" and use autocomplete but they still navigate quickly between available packages. Later "-y" argument is added they type "-?" again and quickly navigate between available params.

Could you please clarify how. Does it have something to do with "-?" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have this functionality, please open Powershell as an administrator and run the following command that will install chocolatey on your computer:

```
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
```

you should get output similar to this:

[image: Chocolatey installation]

after installation has finished, close Powershell window and reopen new one.

now try the following command:

write `choco` followed by a space ----> now press tab, and see if you are able to cycle through the available commands :)

basically they wrote a powershell ( Module ) "as i wrote in the comments" and later they .sourced it (dot sourced) to allow this functionality.

you can review this script by following this path:

> c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\ChocolateyTabExpansion.ps1

Answer (score 2):

you can use `TAB` key to closest Powershell command complete . and if you have new powershell on windows 10 you can use `CONTROL + SPACE` to see all of available command intellisense . you can also use powershell_ise.exe to see GUI of written script and edit it easy .

example :

write >> `get-comm` and then press `TAB` this will be complete with `get-command` 
write >> 'get-pr' and then press `TAB` this will be complete with `Get-PrintConfiguration` and press `TAB` again you wull see `Get-Printer` and so on to switch between commands.

Comment: In my win10 PS, `CONTROL + SPACE` won't give out all available options.

Answer (score 0):

Chocolatey is a global PowerShell execution engine using the *NuGet packaging* infrastructure. Chocolatey is something you need if you have ever installed, upgraded, or removed software on Windows.

Just press and up and down arrow for getting the older commands that had been run in the console.

And for getting the auto-completion which is known as **powershell intellisense** you just need to hit **TAB**

For installing it use : [Install Chocolatey Now](https://chocolatey.org/)

Chocolatey is one of the most useful package manager for Windows.

Then all the native commands for it as well as the intellisense on that commad type will work as showing in the GIF.

Hope this clarifies your need.

Comment: @JungleJeem: I hope you are clear now. Just type the letter(s) first followed by TAB. you will get the completion of the command. Keep on hitting TAB it will toggle through all the commands under that letter(s).

Comment: It looks like they have a powershell module

Comment: @YanivK: Buddy . Powershell is a cmd line shell which does Windows Automation and give full exposure to COM and WMI. Type Powershell in Run, you will get the shell and there you can try this intellisense. All PS version have them. It seems you are very new to it. Go through the PS documentation

Comment: @RanadipDutta  I'm aware of autocomplete and tab. However this is not the case here. The user initially types "-?" and then quickly navigates between "search", "list", "install", "upgrade" etc. Then they type "no" and use autocomplete but they still navigate quickly between available packages. Later "-y" argument is added they type "-?" again and quickly navigate between available params.

Could you please clarify how. Does it have something to do with "-?" ?

Comment: @YanivK does it have anything to do with -?

Comment: Autocompleate doesn't work like that for external exe and programs. Powershell autocomplete only works for internal cmdlets.

Comment: Once again it could work only if chocolatey wrote a powershell module for Powershell. May be some digging on their website would clear things a bit :)

Comment: But even if they don't have it, you could write the same functionality by yourself:)

Comment: @YanivK : Let me clarify you. If you want to download something from [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) then you can use choco install so and so.
Chocolatey is a package manager for windows which you can utilize then all the cmdlets whatever showing in the  screen will work because after this installation for PS cmdlets are native

Comment: Dutta: please don't clarify me. If you have an answer to OPs original question, than post an answer...!

Comment: I have updated the answer and one more thing the inteliisense works with current folder applications also apart from native cmdlets. Please try it it will be there.

Comment: JungelJeem: it appears that For years Chocolatey has allowed you to extend Chocolatey with your own PowerShell modules and functions.

Comment: @YanivK: If you want further, Lets have a screensharing . I will show it how it functions. try giving tab on C:\ after that see it natively  completes the apps/folder also under that the normal shell behavior.

Comment: @Ranadip: I am very well familiar with TAB an autocomplete.
For my understanding OP want the same behavior as Powershell internal Cmdlets e.g. Get-Service [[-Name] <String[]>] [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-DependentServices ] [-Exclude <String[]>] [-Include <String[]>] [-RequiredServices ] [<CommonParameters>]

all thous parameters and switches will be shown if you press TAB and cycle through them.

Comment: I have mentioned everything. Could you check everything.

Comment: not with this command . Even directly give .\ and hit TAB it will show current working directory stuffs. Choco does the same. and please carefully read it.

Comment: @YanivK that's exactly what I'm looking for. Please submit your answer outside of the comments so I can accept it as the solution. Warmly.

Comment: @JungleJeem: following your warm request :) , i submitted my answer.

Comment: @Yanivk: whats the diff in my ans ?

Comment: @RanadipDutta you're not really answering what Im asking and you insist that it's correct. Like I said i know of tab completion. I use bash regularly and spend a lot of time on linux distros. However the tab auto completion is not what i'm asking for.